# Autosuggestbox doesn't display the suggestionlist when I set the property Grid.Row=0. How to expand the result list downwards?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid Name="ggrid" Canvas.ZIndex="0" Background="{StaticResource bg_color}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <AutoSuggestBox Name="suggestion_box" Grid.Row="0" TextChanged="suggestion_box_TextChanged" UpdateTextOnSelect="True"  QuerySubmitted="suggestion_box_QuerySubmitted"/>


        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Name="main_sp">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <StackPanel Name="datepanel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                    <TextBlock Text="Date:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource accent_color}" />
                    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Name="day_box" PlaceholderText="Day" />
                    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Name="month_box" PlaceholderText="Month" />
                    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Name="year_box" PlaceholderText="Year" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="30,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="Invoice No." Foreground="{StaticResource accent_color}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBox Name="Invoice_No" BorderThickness="0" Margin="10,0,10,0" PlaceholderText="2001" Foreground="{StaticResource accent_color}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="/" Margin="10,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource accent_color}"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox Name="Year1" BorderThickness="0" Margin="10,0,10,0" PlaceholderText="17" Foreground="{StaticResource accent_color}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="-" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource accent_color}" />
                        <TextBlock Name="Year2" Text="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource accent_color}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Name="challan_sp" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Button Name="Challan_Add_button" Margin="10" Content="Add Challan" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="{StaticResource accent_color}" FontSize="32" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Click="Challan_Add_button_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

             <Button Grid.Row="2" Name="Save_button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Save" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="{StaticResource accent_color}" FontSize="32"  Click="Save_button_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}"/>


    </Grid>

</ScrollViewer>
```

When I set the Row.Grid="0" for the autosuggestbox, it doesn't display the suggestionlist. But, when I set the Row.Grid="3", it displays the suggestionlist.

It would be helpful if I would be able to expand the list downwards while setting the Row.Grid="0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set main grid (ggrid) properties : 
`VerticalAligment = "Strench" HorizontalAligment = "Strench"`

**EDIT**

Checked your code , is running perfect on my PC. I suppose this scrollviewer is child of other control

Comment: Got solved. I was using TextBlock as AutoSuggestBox items. Replacing textblocks with list did the job.